# DropDownList Database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a DB and a DropDownList, but this always only shows System.Data.DataRowView. What can I do? My code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:campingConnectionString2 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:campingConnectionString2.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Distinct LandDE FROM campingplatz ORDER BY LandDE ASC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties for the list, so it knows what columns in the DataRow to look at.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand that. Can you do it on my code, please!

<asp:DropDownList ID="LandList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoPostBack="True" DataMember="DefaultView" DataTextField="LandDE" DataValueField="LandDE">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:campingConnectionString2 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:campingConnectionString2.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Distinct LandDE FROM campingplatz ORDER BY LandDE ASC"></asp:SqlDataSource>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are always quite a few ways to do this.

I often don't use a "datasource" imbeeded in the markup. They are often less then easy to deal with. (but, I'll often use the wizard to setup the dropdown, as it does setup the columns etc.

but, lets say we have two combo boxes. One for City, and then when you select the city then the 2nd combo box fills with hotels from that city.

So we have this markup:

```
 <div style="font-size:x-large">
        Select City:
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" width="150px" style="margin-right:25px"
                DataValueField="City" DataTextField="City" 
                AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="cboCity_TextChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>

        Select Hotel:
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotels" runat="server" width="150px" 
            DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="HotelName">
        </asp:DropDownList>


    </div>
```

And then some code to fill the first combo box, and the 2nd one like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then

        ' load combo box (City)
        Using cmdSQL As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT City from tblCity ORDER BY City",
                                      New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
            cboCity.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
            cboCity.DataBind()
            ' add blank row to combo
            cboCity.Items.Insert(0, "")
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub cboCity_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' fill hotels combo based on city
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotels WHERE City = @City ORDER BY HotelName"

    Using cmdSQL As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboCity.SelectedValue
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        cboHotels.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        cboHotels.DataBind()
    End Using

End Sub
```

So now we get say this:

[image]

So we did set autopostback = true for the first combo, and when the user selected the city, then we use that city value to fill the 2nd combo with a list of hotels from that city.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not understand that. Can you do that on my code, please?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="LandList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoPostBack="True" DataMember="DefaultView" DataTextField="LandDE" DataValueField="LandDE">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:campingConnectionString2 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:campingConnectionString2.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Distinct LandDE FROM campingplatz ORDER BY LandDE ASC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question? If so, please be more clear. If you're just commenting, don't do this with an answer. Just comment under the answer you want to comment (if you have the privilege to do it). To answer a question with a comment is considered a bad practice. Please see [ask], [answer] and [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: And also, try to format code as code. See [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).